# Problems of **arg in Python

Tags: python

I'll post my code first, and then ask questions.

```
def menu(**arg):
    if len(arg) == 0:
        name = raw_input("Enter your name: ")
        location = raw_input("Enter your name: ")
    else:
        for i,j in arg.items():
            globals()[i] = j
    print "Name: %s | Location: %s" % (name, location)
```

The goal of this function is to print out something like this:

> Name: someone | Location: somewhere

If I just input

> menu()

OK, no problem, but if I type

> menu(name='someone', location='somewhere')

something went wrong...

If I rewrite it like this:

```
def menu(**arg):
    if len(arg) == 0:
        pass
    else:
        for i,j in arg.items():
            globals()[i] = j
    print "Name: %s | Location: %s" % (name, location)
```

and I type

> menu(name='someone', location='somewhere')

it worked... but I don't know why

Also, why can't I replace vars() with globals() in the "rewritten version"?  
  
And my last question is ...  
I found this code verbose and redundant..  
Is there any way to make it cleaner and neater?

Thanks for your patience!

Comment: It's not good practice to use a blanket `except`. Especially when you don't know if you code will work. Try taking it out so we and you have an error message to work with.

Comment: What is the purpose of your `try:`-`except:` statements? Do you realize that they are hiding the actual error from you?

Comment: `for i, j in arg.items(): globals()[i] = j` -- the goggles, they do nothing! This is horrible, even discounting the reasons it doesn't work. *If* you insist on doing both things (prompting for input or accepting the input as parameters) in one function, *at least* explicitly use `arg['name']` and `arg['location']`. Or forget about keyword arguments and accept two "normal" parameters `name` and `location` which default to `None`, and check wether `name is None`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll answer your last question:

> Is there any way to make it cleaner and neater?

For example:

```
def menu(name=None, location=None):
    if name is None:
        name = raw_input("Enter your name: ")
    if location is None:
        location = raw_input("Enter your location: ")
    print "Name: %s | Location: %s" % (name, location)
```

Answer (score 11):

First of all, don't modify `globals` -- that's unnecessary and overly complex. If `len(args) == 0`, just create a dictionary called `args` with a `name` and a `location` value.

The actual problem with the code, however, is that once you define `location` and `name` *anywhere* in the function -- even in an `if` clause -- Python expects that `location` and `name` will be local variables. So then when you refer to `location` and `name`, Python looks for them in the local namespace, doesn't find them, and throws an `UnboundLocalError`.

```
>>> x = 1
>>> def foo():
...     if False:
...         x = 2
...     print x
... 
>>> foo()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in foo
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: @Owen Liu, also, I strongly agree with `delnan`'s suggestion to use `name` and `location` parameters explicitly in the signature of `foo`, with `None` default values. That's much more idiomatic than what you're doing with `**arg` here.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of wondering what's wrong with the code, **let Python tell you**.

Let's run it:

```
def menu(**arg):
    if len(arg) == 0:
        name = raw_input("Enter your name: ")
        location = raw_input("Enter your name: ")
    else:
        for i,j in arg.items():
            globals()[i] = j
    print "Name: %s | Location: %s" % (name, location)
```

We get something like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 8, in menu
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'name' referenced before assignment
```

The `print` line tries to use `name`. The exception indicates that this is a local variable, and that it hasn't been assigned. Of course the local variable hasn't been assigned, since we skipped the `if` block where those assignments occur, and instead ran code to update `globals`.

We **don't want to update globals for something like this anyway**; if the asked-for variables should be local, then why on earth should user-supplied variables be global? It's especially strange to take things that could have been passed in as locals, bypass that by using `**args`, and then forcibly stuff them into globals instead. Just doesn't make any sense.

The remaining question: why doesn't Python check globals for the name and location? Simple: the presence of code - even if it doesn't run, because this is configured at compile-time - that assigns to `name` and `location` causes the compiler to recognize those as possible locals. The local scope is tighter than the global scope, and thus is preferred.

To write code that assigns to a global (without using `globals()`), you need to tell Python explicitly that the name you're using should refer to a global variable, with the `global` keyword.